# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called even when [objects count] in numberOfRowsInSection shows 46 objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

About to pull my hair on this one. 
My tableview stopped loading the data all of a sudden. 
I have breakpoints in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. `numberOfRowsInSection` which goes like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [objects count];
}
```

gets called thrice, for some reason, when the view initially loads with the number of objects in the `objects` array being 0 which can be understood because the tableview doesn't have any data initially.

After I fetch data from the server and store those objects in my `objects` array and call `[self.tableView reloadData];`, `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called again with the number of objects in `objects` array this time being 46 but it still doesn't go ahead and enter `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for some reason.

I have tried reloading the data on the main thread -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

No use.

I have checked all my spellings.

Checked that my `UITableView` object is not nil when I am reloading the data.

The frame of the table view is 320.0000*568.0000 in `viewDidLoad`.

No idea what's going wrong. And I am assuming I broke something because the data was loading just fine earlier.

Comment: plz also check properly the cellForRowAtIndexPath method's spell and name. Many users are suffering from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are loading the view from another view, then you should **call [tableView reloadData] on ViewDidLoad also update dataSource array there**. This is because of the view life cycle - when you are coming back from one view and your tableView data source is updated, the view life cycle will be like this:

1. **viewDidLoad**
2. **tableViewDelegateMethods**
3. **viewDidAppear**

So when you update tableView's data source object and call reloadData during viewDidLoad will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.tableView beginUpdates];`

I have no idea when and why I added this and then forgot to call `endUpdates`. Sigh.

Thanks community. Huge help!